# How do I set node app to run on a static port number on heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

my node app runs on port 8083 locally. when I push to heroku, how can I configure the service to run on the same port?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it. Your code should listen on the port that you have in the PORT environment variable passed to you by the Heroku server that you can access as `process.env.PORT` and Heroku will listen on the outside on port 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS.

See the docs:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles

In particular:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#web-dynos
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Correct example:

```
// Get the port:
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
// Listen on the port:
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Listening on', PORT));
```

The default (3000 in this example) is for situations when you run it outside of Heroku (like for testing). When it is run on Heroku it should always listen on the port provided by Heroku. If it listens on some other port then Heroku will not proxy the traffic to your app correctly.

Comment: @techtransferportal You wouldn't. You should `.listen(process.env.PORT || SOME_DEFAULT_PORT)` because Heroku will always set the PORT for you and it will not proxy the traffic to your app if you listen on a different port than the one supplied by Heroku.